# Clearing a counter after each function call: JavaScript Recursive function

Tags: javascript, recursion, parameters

I have the folllowing solution to a problem relating to multiplicative persistence. However, I need to wipe the counter after each function call.
I have tried different return statements, counters and arrays.

I don't seem to be able to clear the counter after each function call AND
get the correct answer. It is adding all the answers from multiple function calls.

```
function persistence(num, counter = 0) {
        if (num.toString().length != 1) {
            num = num.toString().split("").filter(Number).reduce((a, b) => a * b);
            persistence(num, ++counter);
        }
return counter;
}


persistence(999) // Answer should be 4.
persistence(25)// Answer should be 2 not 6 or 1.
```

The tests here:

```
describe('Initial Tests', function () {
      Test.assertEquals(persistence(39),3);
      Test.assertEquals(persistence(4),0);
      Test.assertEquals(persistence(25),2);
      Test.assertEquals(persistence(999),4);
    });
```

Comment: You're probably looking for `counter = persistence(num, counter+1)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the result of each recursive call and handle the else case.

Try this:

```
function persistence(num, counter = 0) {
  if (num.toString().length != 1) {
    num = num.toString().split("").filter(Number).reduce((a, b) => a * b);
    return persistence(num, ++counter);
  } else {
    return counter;
  }
}
```

Here are the results from console:

```
> persistence(25)
< 2
> persistence(999)
< 4
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're trying to compute [multiplicative digital root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_digital_root) but that does **not** remove zeroes from the computation as you're doing with `.filter(Number)` above. Below, we write `multiplicativeRoot` which returns an array of the steps it takes to reduce a number to a single digit

Finally, the [multiplicative persistence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistence_of_a_number) can be computed by simply counting the number of steps in the return value from `multiplicativeRoot` and subtracting `1` (the first value in the result is always the input value)

The result is an implementation of `multiplicativePersistence` that is made up of several functions, each with their distinct and clear purpose

```js
const digits = n =>
  n < 10
    ? [ n ]
    : digits (n / 10 >> 0) .concat ([ n % 10 ])

const mult = (x,y) =>
  x * y

const product = xs =>
  xs.reduce (mult, 1)

const multiplicativeRoot = x =>
  x < 10
    ? [ x ]
    : [ x ] .concat (multiplicativeRoot (product (digits (x))))
  
const multiplicativePersistence = x =>
  multiplicativeRoot (x) .length - 1
  
console.log (multiplicativeRoot (999))        // [ 999, 729, 126, 12, 2 ]
console.log (multiplicativePersistence (999)) // 4


console.log (multiplicativeRoot (25))         // [ 25, 10, 0 ]
console.log (multiplicativePersistence (25))  // 2
```

Comment: Thanks for this really detailed post. It really helped me understand how to deal with unexpected behaviour through greater abstraction. However, I am afraid that I  still don't understand your objection to removing zeros. The simplest reason behind this was that anything multiplied zero is zero. This code is heads and shoulders above me and it will take some time to digest. Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: @Andrew well it's not that I have a personal objection, it's that zeroes aren't withheld from the product when computing the multiplicative root – the wiki entry makes that pretty clear