# how to keep the value of a counter var using recursion if every time the recursive call is made the var is set back to its initial value

Tags: javascript, recursion

I am very new to programming and specifically to js and I am working in a problem where I have to return the number of times a given number (argument) need to multiply its digits until it becomes a one digit number (less than 10). I know my general logic works except for the counter. I can't figure out a way to keep its value from the previous recursive calls (without modifying the number of arguments I get to pass to the function itself). it is always being set back to 0. Is there anything obvious I am missing in my logic?

my code so far :

```
function persistence(num) {
   var countTimes  = 0;   // it will always go back to zero here 
   var numToArr = String(num).split('').map(nums => Number(nums));
   var resultOfMultNumDigits = numToArr.reduce(function (a,b) {return a * b},1);
   if (resultOfMultNumDigits < 10){
     return countTimes; 
   }else {
   countTimes += 1;  // increases here every time the case base isn't reach
   return persistence(resultOfMultNumDigits);
   }
}
```

Comment: what would you like to get, the count of recursive calls and/or the result of the multiplications?

Comment: move the line `var countTimes = 0;` outside your function??

Comment: both, the count of the recursive calls and the result of the multiplication are integers... @NinaScholz

Comment: If I move counTimes outside the function, the result will accumulate the times I call the function in other numbers. @ADyson

Comment: Then you perhaps need to reset it each time before you start the recursion. Often recursion patterns end up with an outer "wrapper" function which sets things up, and the inner function which is the one which is called recursively. A caller wanting to use the recursion would actually call the outer function and the outer function then kicks off the recursion by calling the inner function for the first time once everything is ready (e.g. in this case, the counter is reset to 0). It's all about context.

Comment: Thanks @ADyson! I also needed to change the position of my base case !  calling a wrapper function was indeed useful.

Answer (score 4):

### TL;DR

When using recursion, having a "counter" variable can be a code smell. Often in recursive code the result you want is the result of some operation in *this* "iteration," combined with the result of the *next* iteration (combined with the result of the *next*, and so on...).

When the result you want is just the number of iterations, the last line of the recursive function (`myFunc`) often looks like this: `return 1 + myFunc(dataForNextIteration);`. That's exactly the case here (where we assume `toDigits` and `product` are functions that do what they say on the tin):

```
function persistence(num) {
  const digits = toDigits(num);
  if (digits.length === 1) {
    return 0;
  }
  return 1 + persistence(product(digits));
}
```

### How to get there

We want to count the "iterations" (). If  starts at 0, the result after  iterations should be . If the input is a one-digit number our work is done, so we just return 0 without further recursion. This is a good place to start writing code.

```
function persistence(num) {
  const digits = toDigits(num);
  if (digits.length === 1) {
    return 0;
  }

  // ...
}
```

This is our "stop case": One digit? Stop recursion and return `0`.

What if `digits.length` is greater than 1, though? Naturally, we want to get the product of `digits` and pass it to the next "iteration" of `persistence`. But what do we do with the result?

Suppose `num` is 123. The product of its digits is 6, which is one digit. We know, then, that the *next* iteration is going to hit our stop case and return `0`. And that means that *this* iteration should return `1`. How do we get `1` from `0`? Add `1`:

```
function persistence(num) {  // num => 123
  const digits = toDigits(num);  // digits => [1, 2, 3];
  if (digits.length === 1) {  // digits.length => 3
    return 0;
  }

  const digitsProduct = product(digits);  // digitsProduct => 6
  const nextResult = persistence(digitsProduct);  // nextResult => 0
  return 1 + nextResult;  // 1 + 0
}
```

This is a little verbose, for the sake of demonstration. You can see it a little less verbose in the working snippet below:

```js
function toDigits(num) {
  return String(num).split('').map(n => parseInt(n));
}

function product(arr) {
  return arr.reduce((prod, n) => prod * n, 1);
}

function persistence(num) {
  const digits = toDigits(num);
  if (digits.length === 1) {
    return 0;
  }
  return 1 + persistence(product(digits));
}

// ...or terser still...
function persistence(num) {
  const d = toDigits(num);
  return d.length === 1 ? 0 : 1 + persistence(product(d));
}

console.log(persistence(5)); // => 0
console.log(persistence(123)); // => 1
console.log(persistence(1234)); // => 2
console.log(persistence(123456)); // => 2
console.log(persistence(999)); // => 4
```

Answer (score 1):

You could return an object with count and value and increment the first part for every recursion.

```js
function persistence(num) {
    var value = num.toString().split('').reduce((a, b) => a * b, 1),
        temp;

    if (value < 10){
        return { count: 0, value };
    }
    temp = persistence(value);
    temp.count++;
    return temp;
}

console.log(persistence(2222222));
console.log(persistence(22222));
console.log(persistence(22));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

> …without modifying the number of arguments I get to pass to the function itself…

There's your solution. If you need more parameters for your recursion, introduce them. To get an initial value of the additional parameters, actually write two functions - a recursive one with as many parameters as you need, and one that has the signature that is to be used from the outside. Then call the helper function from the exposed function.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to calculate multiplicative root and persistence – I've [already answered this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43690023/633183)

```js
const digits = n =>
  n < 10
    ? [ n ]
    : digits (n / 10 >> 0) .concat ([ n % 10 ])

const mult = (x,y) =>
  x * y

const product = xs =>
  xs.reduce (mult, 1)

const multiplicativeRoot = x =>
  x < 10
    ? [ x ]
    : [ x ] .concat (multiplicativeRoot (product (digits (x))))
  
const multiplicativePersistence = x =>
  multiplicativeRoot (x) .length - 1
  
console.log (multiplicativeRoot (999))        // [ 999, 729, 126, 12, 2 ]
console.log (multiplicativePersistence (999)) // 4

console.log (multiplicativeRoot (25))         // [ 25, 10, 0 ]
console.log (multiplicativePersistence (25))  // 2
```