# Multiplicative Persistence Codewars Challenge

Tags: javascript

I've been working on a kata from Codewars, the challenge is to write a function, persistence, that takes in a positive parameter num and returns its multiplicative persistence, which is the number of times you must multiply the digits in num until you reach a single digit.

Example:

```
persistence(39) === 3 // because 3*9 = 27, 2*7 = 14, 1*4=4
                       // and 4 has only one digit

persistence(999) === 4 // because 9*9*9 = 729, 7*2*9 = 126,
                        // 1*2*6 = 12, and finally 1*2 = 2

persistence(4) === 0 // because 4 is already a one-digit number
```

While trying to figure this out I came across a solution online (shown below) and after trying to understand its logic, I couldn't see why the code didn't work

```
var count = 0;

function persistence(num) {
  if (num.toString().length === 1) {
    return count;
  }
  count++;
  var mult = 1;
  var splitStr = num.toString().split("");
  for (var i = 0; i <= splitStr; i++) {
    mult *= parseFloat(splitStr[i])
  }
  return persistence(parseFloat(mult));
}
```

The output for any single digit number will be 0 which is correct however for any number that is multiple digits, the persistence always logs as 1 and I can't seem to figure out why, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you're asking why the second piece of code acts as it does, it would be better not to confuse the issue by showing the other code. Also, both pieces of code use a `for` loop, neither show a `while`....

Comment: Also, the code as posted results in something different, since `count` is only set to 0 the first time it is run...

Comment: The second function is bad, it depends on global variable `count`, so it gives different result according to when it was called. It should be rewritten to `return 0` and `return 1 + persistence(...)` and not use global `count` at all.

Comment: _I came across a solution proposed here on Stack Overflow_ - a link would probably be useful. Also, you are asking why somebody else's code doesn't work?

Comment: @HereticMonkey Apologies, I posted the wrong piece of code but I've now removed it as I can see why it would be confusing.

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43698314/633183) may interest you

Comment: @user633183 The OP knows how to solve the issue; they are specifically asking why the posted code does not work.

Comment: @MattBurland Sorry about that, I was looking for the original source and realised it was on coderbyte so I've edited my post accordingly (not sure if you can link outside Stack Overflow). Im trying to understand why the code doesn't work as I've read through it and am unsure where the issue lies exactly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The posted code has quite a few problems.

```
for (var i = 0; i <= splitStr; i++) {
```

But `splitStr` is an array, not a number; `i <= splitStr` doesn't make sense. It should check against `splitStr.length` instead of `splitStr`.

Another problem is that it should use `i <`, not `i <=`, else the final `splitStr[i]` will be `undefined`.

Another problem is that the `count` variable is global, so more than one call of `persistence` will result in inaccurate results. There's no need for a `count` variable at all. To fix it:

```js
function persistence(num) {
  if (num.toString().length === 1) {
    return 0;
  }
  var mult = 1;
  var splitStr = num.toString().split("");
  for (var i = 0; i < splitStr.length; i++) {
    mult *= parseFloat(splitStr[i])
  }
  return 1 + persistence(parseFloat(mult));
}

console.log(
  persistence(999),
  persistence(39),
  persistence(4)
);
```

Or, one could avoid the `for` loop entirely, and use more appropriate array methods:

```js
function persistence(num) {
  const str = num.toString();
  if (str.length === 1) {
    return 0;
  }
  const nextNum = str.split('').reduce((a, b) => a * b, 1);
  return 1 + persistence(nextNum);
}

console.log(
  persistence(999),
  persistence(39),
  persistence(4)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Better try this i completed Persistent Bugger kata by this script.

```
function persistence(num) {
  let count = 0;
  while(num.toString().length > 1){
    num = num.toString().split('').reduce((acc,el)=>acc *= +el,1)
    count++
  }
  return count
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### or we can use while loop with reduce array method

```
const persistence=(num)=>{

  let splitNumArr=num.toString().split('')
  let newList
  let count=0
  while(splitNumArr.length>1){

     newList=splitNumArr.reduce((acc,curr)=>{
        return acc*=curr
     })
      splitNumArr=newList.toString().split('')
      count++

  }

return count
}



console.log(persistence(39))===3
console.log(persistence(999))===4
console.log(persistence(9))===0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function persistence(num) {
   var times = 0;
   
   num = num.toString();
   
   while (num.length > 1) {
     times++;
     num = num.split('').map(Number).reduce((a, b) => a * b).toString();
   }
   
   return times;
}
```