# i wanna solve using recursive function.. but can't solve it

Tags: javascript, recursion

```
function test3(num) {
    value = value * Number(str[i]);
    let value = 1;
    let str = String(num);
    for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        if (str.length <= 1) {
        }
        return test3(value);
    }
    return value;
}
```

i wanna make single Digits using recursive function.
but, the code's value can't access..
i m searching in google about recursive fuction, it's not good answer..
why cant access 'value' ?

i wanna make

```
234,
2* 3* 4
2* 4
8

786,
7 * 8 * 6 -> 336
3 * 3 * 6 -> 54
5 * 4 -> 20
2 * 0 -> 0
```

like that. i want to know why can't access 'value' in the function.
thank you.

Comment: I would start again. looks like you're trying to solve a problem by adding more code. For example, you're trying to access str on line 2, when you actually declare it on line 4. Start small!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't access variables form the parent function's scope. If you want to access variables, pass them in as a parameter. Regardless, this is much easier done without strings:

```js
function productOfDigits(num) {
    if (num < 10) {
        return num;
    }
    return (num % 10) * productOfDigits(Math.floor(num / 10));
}

// use this one
function repeatedProductOfDigits(num) {
    if (num < 10) {
        return num;
    }
    // multiply all the digits then try again
    return repeatedProductOfDigits(productOfDigits(num));
}
```

`num % 10` gets the last digit, and `Math.floor(num / 10)` gets every digit except the last, so `productOfDigits(786) == 6 * productOfDigits(78) == 6 * 8 * productOfDigits(7) == 6 * 8 * 7`.

Comment: Note, though, that this is only a step in the OP's requirements, which wants repeated calls to this function until the value is under 10.

Comment: @ScottSauyet I don't think I understand what you're saying. This function is being repeatedly called until the value under 10.

Comment: `234` is over 10, so `234 => 2 * 3 * 4 == 24`.  Still over 10.  so `24 => 2 * 4 = 8`.  Under 10, so return 8.  Similarly `786 --> 7 * 8 * 6 = 336 --> 3 * 3 * 6 = 54 --> 5 * 4 = 20 --> 2 * 0 = 0`.  I'ts an easy recursion atop yours:  `const reduceProductOfDigits = (n) => n < 10 ? n : reduceProductOfDigits (productOfDigits(n))`, but as it stands, you solve a simpler problem.

Comment: @ScottSauyet Ah, I see. I've edited something in.

Comment: @Aplet123 Thank you :)   I didn't think that way ! using Math.floor method.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are trying to calculate the [multiplicative digital root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_digital_root) -

```js
const multRoot = n =>
  n < 10
    ? n
    : multRoot(product(digits(n)))

const digits = n =>
  n < 10
    ? [ n ]
    : [ ...digits(Math.floor(n / 10)), n % 10 ]

const product = ns =>
  ns.reduce(mult, 1)

const mult = (m, n) =>
  m * n
    
console.log(multRoot(234)) // 8
console.log(multRoot(786)) // 0
```

To see a variant of this problem, read [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43698314/633183).